# Sound problems on Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox

When I visit this [online dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) and try to listen how a word is pronounced I get this following error:

[image]

But this error disappears when I try that on Windows or my phone.

Note that `firefox -v` outputs: `Mozilla Firefox 38.0`.

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Works OK for me (also Firefox 38 and 14.04). Here Firefox is trying to play an .mp3 or .ogg audio format file. Check if you can open these file types using Firefox. You should be able to tell whether the problem is in Firefox, system (by opening such file types with another application) or the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question by diving into the [official Ubuntu documentation related to restricted formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

As mentioned there, I resolved the problem by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I restarted Ubuntu and everything is working fine.

Hope this can help someone else in the future.